# AngularJS success callBack not called after an already defined promise

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm new to AngularJS and i was testing the fact that successCallback *then(successCallback, [errorCallback], [notifyCallback])* method could be called even if the promise was already resolved with the following code :

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        deferred.resolve("finished !");
    });
}, 3000);
var promise = deferred.promise;

    setTimeout(function() {
    promise.then(function(result) {
    alert(result);
    });
}, 4000);
```

My alert doesn't appear, if i change *4000* to *2000*.

Can somebody explain me why *then(successCallback, [errorCallback], [notifyCallback])* method when the promise is already resolved ?

Thanks,

Valentin

Comment: It got work for both cases you mentioned, [check here](https://plnkr.co/edit/o8JqsS8AOn7RH759EM9j?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm confused i tested the code on jsfiddle and it did not work.

Comment: You might be expecting something else. Please explain

Comment: No, you answered to my question ty for your help :)

Comment: Np, you could delete you question as it isn't valid to ask..